How would this circuit work with a directly heated cathode?
I am looking at designs for vacuum-tube LC oscillators, and have settled on a Colpitts configuration(only one inductor needed). However, looking at the design below from this website,  it uses an indirectly heated cathode(heater connections not shown) compared to the directly heated types I currently have.

Since the cathode in the above circuit is connected to ground, would the following (redrawn) circuit still work?
My assumption here is the grounded cathode from the original schematic works the same as the grounded end of the cathode(filament) in the redrawn schematic. (I am not terribly familiar with vacuum tube based designs, especially as the tubes in my collection are well over 50 years old).


Yes your oscillator should work. Your little battery valves will have less transconductance so if it does not start reliably then increase the feedback and don't forget to place a choke in the B+ line to allow voltage feedback.

That last bit is worth further emphasizing: the schematics are out and out wrong, as "B+" implies a voltage source that completely shorts out any AC plate signal. An RFC is required here, of large enough value not to interfere with oscillator operation. Or a resistor, of sufficient value and assuming enough B+ is available for the drop.

@TimWilliams Why would a choke/resistor be needed on the B+ line(apart from plate short)? Doesn't a choke basically act like a filter for HF noise?

@lemon Exactly. You want to make sure the supply doesn't act like a short and prevent any output--obviously, trying to take the output directly off the battery positive terminal isn't going to work.

Addressing OP's comment on another answer,

Why would a choke/resistor be needed on the B+ line(apart from plate short)? Doesn't a choke basically act like a filter for HF noise?


Principles used: AC equivalent circuit, supernode, the assumption marked.
For this to oscillate, Zg would have to be a negative resistance, but you'll be hard pressed to find a normally-biased triode with such a characteristic.
Some plate-circuit impedance is required so that the plate node has some AC voltage, which then couples through the tank network to the grid and creates oscillation.
The direct-heating doesn't matter, and yes this is a correct connection for it, given the rest of the circuit works properly of course.
A bypass capacitor on the A+ terminal will suffice to ensure low cathode impedance; given the low gm of these types, this won't be required for performance reasons, it's just a good idea to avoid crosstalk into other heater circuits.

The original 1927 patent from Edwin Colpitts himself shows a vacuum tube oscillator with a directly heated cathode.

The component symbols are different from our modern ones, but I don't think it's very difficult to figure out. As Tim pointed out, the schematic from that webpage has been simplified to the point where it can't work. It needs at least a choke.
